# NSolid Proxt Failed to parse request body

Tags: node.js, nsolid

The console and proxy seem to be communicating, but the proxy fails to parse the data. It looks like it is url encoded, and the proxy is just trying to JSON.parse

The data is like

```
%7B%22pid%22%3A332%2C%22hostname%22%3A%221b76cdf77590%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22nsolid-default%22%2C%22address%22%3A%22172.21.0.4%3A34134%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228344f1e87b23a5b89d44028160b3c7a1fdbac6db%22%7D
```

If I run decodeURIComponent on it first, then it looks like something that is Parsable

Also the console keeps saying

`POLLING ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000`

Even though I have HSOLID_HUB set, and it is sucessfully talking to the proxy.

Any Ideas.

Comment: This is with 1.6.11 console

Comment: How looks like your launch command for the proxy?

Comment: Was my bad. I had the hosts for proxy and etc mixed up.The downloads page calls it the hub - but is really the proxy. The docs refer to etc as the hub. I would recommed dropping the word "Hub" all together. There are only 2 pieces. for NSolid The proxy and console. You need to stand up an Etcd2 as a dependency. Less confusing

Comment: Daniel, The documentation seems to use hub / proxy and etcd interchangably.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'll take a look. S̶e̶v̶e̶r̶a̶l̶ ̶t̶i̶m̶e̶s̶?̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶p̶e̶c̶i̶f̶i̶c̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶t̶?̶